# Window getch vs Curses getch in Ruby

Tags: ruby, curses

I'm currently learning to use Ruby and the curses library, and I tried my hand at making a simple application that accepts two characters and exits. However, I'm a bit confused as to the difference between a "window" instance of an object and a Curses instance.

For example, I have the script below that attempts to use the "getch" functionality of the library in two ways: One using the `Curses::getch` and the other using `$window.getch`

```
def init_curses()
  Curses::init_screen
  win = Curses::Window.new( Curses.lines, Curses.cols, #Set window to be as large as terminal window
                            0, 0) #Start window on top-left corner
  win.clear
  return win
end

$window = init_curses
input_ch = nil

begin
  Curses::crmode
  $window.addstr(INPUT_STR)

  # Changing the order of these two lines
  # changes what I see on the screen
  Curses::refresh
  $window.refresh

  # Read characters using different methods
  input_ch = $window.getch
  input_ch = Curses::getch
ensure 
  $window.clear #Prevent output after exiting
  $window.close
  Curses::close_screen
end
```

When I change the order of the calls to refresh (now calling `$window.refresh` before `Curses::refresh`, nothing appears on the screen.

Why is this?

Additionally, is there some preferred method of getting input? Should I get input through `window.getch` or `Curses::getch`? Are there benefits and drawbacks to each?

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's curses is just an interface to the C curses library.

Curses *windows* are typically smaller than the *screen*.  In curses, as a special case, there is a predefined window **`stdscr`** which corresponds to the whole screen.

In each case (a user-defined *window* or the special window **`stdscr`**) you can use `getch` in some way to read "from" the window.  What that means is that while reading from the window, curses moves the cursor into that window at the current position (for that window), and depending on the options, may echo the input characters.  Also (because of the movement and echoing), curses keeps the window up to date using `refresh`.